# /usr/sbin/grub never finishes

Tags: 12.04, server, grub2

I did `apt-get upgrade` it never finishes at this point:

```
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-virtual
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

You already have a NoLOADER configuration in /etc/grub.conf
Running boot loader as requested
Running /usr/sbin/grub  ...
```

The system does not freeze (Ctrl-Z works, I get my console back) just that that /usr/sbin/grub seems to never complete.

What should I do?

Comment: Related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/184488/rollback-instead-of-completing-dpkg-configure-a

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be an issue with the file `/etc/grub.conf`. [Removing the file and re-configuring seems to work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=861506&p=5777976#post5777976):

```
sudo mv /etc/grub.conf /etc/grub.conf.$(date +%F)
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Thanks to whoever awarded the bounty points. I'm glad the answer was useful to you.