# Rollback instead of completing dpkg-configure -a?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, aptitude

On a new VPS, `aptitude dist-upgrade` hangs during `/usr/sbin/grub`.

Now, aptitude is in a bad state:

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I can't successfully complete this command, because of `/usr/sbin/grub` hanging.

Can I rollback instead?

(This is on 12.04)

Comment: Related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/172531/usr-sbin-grub-never-finishes

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I wouldn't like to see this question deleted (it frames the issue slightly different), but I believe it's a dupe. The answer in the linked question worked for me.